# Java PreparedStatement can't identify placeholders in subquery

Tags: java, postgresql

When using a Java PreparedStatement, the question-mark placeholders aren't being detected.  It would throw an error "The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0"  when invoking *statementName*.setLong(1, 123).  My example is from Postgres 8.4, but the problem occurs before the SQL has a chance to make it to the SQL server.

After comparing against some working prepared statements, I realized that the broken one contained a subquery similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT (name) 
    id, 
    name 
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE id > ?
  ORDER BY name) AS Level1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Post the java code block that throws the exception, not only the query. The query is ok, but the problem may be in the way you are writing your java code

Comment: The index for the parameters is 1-based.

Comment: postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to convert the query to a CTE (Common Table Expression).  The revised query looks like this:

```
WITH Level1 AS ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT (name) 
    id, 
    name 
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE id > ?
  ORDER BY name)

SELECT * 
FROM Level1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Alright things just get more weird.  I was able to reproduce this problem on another lengthy query string by stripping out all the Eclipse auto-inserted \r\n escape codes. It's not a space padding problem either, as replacing \r\n with a space doesn't solve it.

Comment: Okay, this is looking more and more like a parsing bug.  Appending --\r\n to the end of the first line of the SQL query makes the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

In JDBC, the parameter indexes for prepared statements begin at 1 instead of 0.